ImportError: cannot import name 'distance' from 'deepface.commons' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/LIP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/deepface/commons/__init__.py)
Unable to import deepface in Python
I am currently using Pycharm on macbook.
Virtual environment is already activated and still getting the below error.
Can anyone please help me here.
Python 3.9
deepface 0.0.89 (latest)
tensorflow version 2.14.1
Virtual environment is already activated.
Everything is installed and still unable to resolve the import error.

distance is missing, but in the code, the is no distance (https://github.com/serengil/deepface/tree/master/deepface/commons).
uninstall the lib and reinstall it according https://github.com/serengil/deepface
you can also check the init.py file
it's seems to be different of the original.

Distance calculation functions moved to modules/verification in the latest version of deepface. You can now consume distance functions as:
from deepface.modules import verification
distance = verification.find_euclidean_distance(x, y)

